# Slidetoggle with div float left

Tags: jquery, css

I am having problem with jquery sliderToggle().  So I have two div with a `float:left;` style property.  I also have a button on each of the div for minimizing and maximizing.

But whenever I hit the button, the div is sort of like min/max'ing relatively to the div next to it instead of min/max'ing on its own.

Here's an example in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Lc46R/

It works fine if I remove the `float:left;` property, but I want to keep the divs next to each other.

Comment: don't really understand how it should look like after minimizing?

Comment: I want the individual window to slide down and keep the other div at its original position/state when minimized

Comment: add some text inside the div. you will notice the div's are minimizing properly. i dont understand what you really want

Comment: @Rhea the div is sliding up when minimizing, not sliding down

Comment: The ``chat-window`` part is still sliding up when I hit the button, but I can't figure out how to get it slide down.  So for example, if I hit the btn on A, the window for A will go up, then when I hit B, both windows will slide down.  What I want to do is, have window A to slide down when I hit btn, while window B is still up.  Its sort of like how the chat tabs in facebook behaves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lc46R/8/

To let the divs slide down when minimizing, use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;` instead of `float: left;`. That's all.

Comment: Hmm, the div is still sliding up for me with inline-block

Comment: Chrome, but I just tried it on firefox and worked.  Is there anyway to get it to work on chrome as well?

Comment: @iyuu Updated, works now in webkit with `vertical-align: bottom;`